# Python Discord Bot using VSCode not detecting on_member_update events

Tags: discord.py

I used to run this bot on replit with no code issues, but after it wiped some JSON files and got API banned, I switched to running it on my PC through VSCode. All functionality works fine, except it doesn't get any response from on_member_update anymore. I didn't change any of the code here, and made sure that all my intents were sorted as well. any ideas?

```
import os
from os import path
import discord
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime, date
from pytz import timezone
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from heapq import nlargest
import random
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print('presence detected')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Of course the vast majority of the code is filtered out, but I feel like this has all the relevant info. Starts fine, runs fine, modifies files fine, doesn't work with detecting presence changes in members. I tried copying the exact code over to replit again, and it detects just fine over there, so it's not the bot settings itself I believe. Maybe i'm missing some import or didn't download a pip or something that it hasn't warned me about? Any help would be great.

Edit 1: Still haven't found a solution to it, but I switched from on_member_update to on_presence_update, which seems to be functionally the same for my purposes. I'm still curious about what's going on though if anyone comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run it through my VS and it works fine for me and on member update it printed `presence detected`
So i don't know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to not having presence intents enabled for your application.
To enable them, go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) and select your application. Navigate to the `Bot` section and you'll then see if you scroll down a little `Presence Intents`. You need to enable this, which is easy enough if you're not verified. Simply click the little switch to turn them on.

If you're bot is verified, you need to apply for the intents. There should be a section for **apply**ing for intents. Fill out the form there and you'll get an email from Discord to progress.

[image: Screenshot of what your bot page (could) looks like]

Comment: Thanks, but sadly all that is already checked and the bot's not verified so I don't believe it's that.

Comment: This isn't possible. If he wouldn't have the intents enabled, his code would crash. He has `Intents.all()` in his code, and if they aren't enabled in the portal then `client.run()` crashes - literally printing an error that says that you're "requesting intents that haven't been enabled on the developer portal". OP says all functionality works fine, so you can assume the bot is able to login, so this can't be the issue.

Comment: @stijndcl That is completely untrue. You do not get an error (atleast on replit) for enabling all intents without actually having some enabled. I have tried it after reading what you said with no error.

Comment: @goose.mp4 then your logging isn't configured properly, because it raises this exception: `discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.`

Comment: @goose.mp4 Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=privilegedintents#discord.PrivilegedIntentsRequired **"Exception that’s raised when the gateway is requesting privileged intents but they’re not ticked in the developer page yet."**. If it's '"completely untrue"' then why is it literally in the docs & on multiple SO questions?

Comment: @stijndcl Then its simply just a replit issue. Again, I had tested it out after you said that on a fresh bot with no verification and I saw no error (as I assumed). This is a replit issue. I own and moderate a discord server for programming, a lot of people have come in with the exact issue and it's not giving them an error because they're using replit.

Comment: @goose.mp4 You shouldn't be using replit to run discord bots but that's another discussion. Replit doesn't hide errors from you, this is raised internally by the library. If your logging is configured properly then you'll get an error.

Comment: @stijndcl I never said I used replit. I don't. Again, this isn't a *me* issue this is just a general issue I've dealt with from others and myself when I first started with making bots (originally started on replit). I never said they hid errors either, I don't know why it doesn't provide the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249463/discussion-between-goose-mp4-and-stijndcl).